# How to call any function if anything happens on the body or document

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### Example

If I create a function name **change_Occur()**. Now i want to call this function if any changes happen in the page.

Comment: What do you consider as "change in the page"?

Comment: What you have tried yet ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Like id don't know what event will occur touch or click or scroll. and when then there event will occur with any element. i want to call change_Occur function.

Comment: I had tried to call in click or touch of body but if i do that my application executes that function more than 10 times.

Comment: You can use angular for this by using $scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*I had tried to call in click or touch of body but if i do that my application executes that function more than 10 times.*"

So I guess if you just want a function to run whenever somebody clicks anything in the body, you could try this.

```
function changeOccur(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onclick = function(){
      alert("clicked body");
    };
}
```

**EDIT:**

Oops, I'm not thinking straight, you want the FUNCTION to run when the user clicks the body, so...

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onclick = function(){
  changeOccur();
};

function changeOccur(){
    alert("oh hey, look at this change that just occurred");
}
```